# Extension of non-first countable space

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, first-countable, dense-subspaces

I have the next question:

Consider $X$ a topological space that is non-first countable. We can assume that $X$ is Tychonoff.

Is there a way to embed $X$ in a topological space $Y$ such that $X$ is dense in $Y$ but, at least, there exist $x\in Y\setminus X$ such that $x$ has a countable local basis? I tried to emulate the construction of the one-point compactification of a topological space but it fails, or maybe I can't prove it, in the first countability of the point at infinity.

The reason of the question comes from the analogous of compactifications: we start with a non compact space and then, we embed it, as a dense subespace, of a compact space. Any hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't assume anything about compactness of $X$, so the idea to use compactification cannot be correct, since $X$ might be its own compactification.

Since you didn't assume any property of $Y$ itself, then there is a quite trivial solution. Consider $Y=X\sqcup \{*\}$ with topology given by: $U\subseteq Y$ is open if and only if $U=Y$ or $U\subseteq X$ is open in $X$.

Clearly $X$ embeds into $Y$. Moreover the only open subset containing $*$ is $Y$ itself, and this implies two things: that the local basis is trivially countable, and that $*$ belongs to the closure of $X$, and so $X$ is dense in $Y$.

Note that I didn't use any assumption on $X$, meaning it literally holds for any topological space $X$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your construction! Clearly, the space $Y = X \sqcup \{*\}$ is not Hausdorff because the point $*$ cannot be separated from the points of $X$. Is there any other form to construct this to ensure that $Y$ is, at least, Hausdorff?

Comment: @CarlosJiménez not really. If $X$ is compact then every embedding $X\to Y$ is closed if $Y$ is Hausdorff. And therefore the image cannot be dense in $Y$, unless the embedding is already a homeomorphism.